# Geb: Defining Page Objects at run time

Tags: xpath, groovy, geb

I am using geb to automate a web application. I want to define a page object, lets call it Page1. depending on the environment, Page1 can have a various number of button elements. In one environment, button 'A' may exist while in another environment button 'A' may not exist.

At Run time I am able to download a list of the expected buttons, per the environment I am using. Lets call this list buttonList. I want to use this list to define my page object at run time.

now this is what I tried to do to solve this problem but it doesn't seem to work. I always get this error: "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild.call()"

```
class Page1 extends Page{
    static def buttonList

    static conntent = {
        buttonList.each{ button ->
            button {$(By.xpath("//*[text() = '${button}']")) }
        }
    }
}
```

normally, if you knew what buttons to expect and they were the same every time you would define the page object like this. but "this" is not an option for me due to what I explained above.

```
class Page1 extends Page{

    static conntent = {
        button1 {$(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'button1']")) }
        button3 {$(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'button3']")) }
        button4 {$(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'button4']")) }
        ...
    }
}
```

in my top level test script I initialize this class so that I can provide this page object the buttonList it requires. this is an abstraction of the top level script code:

```
def "Test Case"(){
    when:
        butList = ["button1", "button3", "button4",...] //this list is generated somewhere else. it's not actually hard coded like you see here. the buttons in the list depend on the environment
        def pageInstance = new Page1()
        pageInstance.buttonList = butList
    then:
        Thread.sleep(30)
    when:
        //click something to bring me to the Page1 page
    then:
        at pageInstance
    when:
        button3.click()//in this case button 3 exists but this is where the code fails 
    then:
        thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

I hope that this some what explains the conundrum I am in. I may be going about solving the entirely wrong way. I am looking for suggestions on how to solve this issue. if the issue is still unclear, feel free to comment and I can attempt make things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I was ever stuck in this situation I'd tackle it like this -

```
class Page1 extends Page{

    static content = {
        allButtons { $("input[type=button]")} 
    }
}
```

Or use some other generic selector for your buttons that will collect them nicely.  Then when I test them I'd go with -

```
def "Are my buttons here"() {
    given: "I am on the conundrum causing page"
        at Page1

    and: "I have some expected button text list"
        def expectedButtonText = ["button1","button4","button5","button6"]

    expect: "All your buttons are belong to us"
        allButtons*.text == expectedButtonText
}
```

Some of this is a little generic but I think you can see the pattern, just collect the allButtons text and compare against an expected list, if this test passes then you should happily be able to refer to individual buttons as below.

```
def "Does my button work"() {
    given: "I am on the conundrum causing page"
        at Page1

    when: "I click on one of the buttons"
        allButtons.find(text: "button1").click()

    then: "magic happens"
        // insert goodness here
}
```

Cheers,
Deon.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add above answer, you always can use the flags wait or required to play a little:

```
static content = 
{ 
    labelBotonEntrar(wait: true,required: false)
    {
        $("div.gwt-label.newButton-label",1)    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong here.

This:

```
class Page1 extends Page{
    static def buttonList

    static conntent = {
        buttonList.each{ button ->
           button {$(By.xpath("//*[text() = '${button}']")) }
        }
    }
}
```

Can be defined as such:

```
class Page1 extends Page{
    static def buttonList

    static conntent = {
        buttonList.each{ button ->
           "${button}" {$(By.xpath("//*[text() = '${button}']")) }
        }
    }
}
```

the static content is a hash map so I can dynamiclly define all of the Keys/variables in the hash map this way.

I am sure some of the oher answers given work, but this is what I was going for when I posted this question orginially.